# python smtplib does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: python, smtplib

Hi I am trying to send out an email through smtplib, I want to keep the username different from the login username. It is giving me an error when I used a shared mailbox which I do have the permission to send and revive emails and port number and works fine with smtp.office365.com.

Anyone know why?

Thank for your help.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("ccc.ccccc.com", 88)  

server.ehlo()

server.starttls()

me = "xxxxxxx@xxx.com"

my_pwd = "xxxxxxxx"

you = ["xxxxxx@xxx.com"]

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

msg['From'] = "yyyyyyyyy@yyy.com"
msg['To'] = ','.join(you)

body = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(body)

server.login(me, my_pwd)

server.sendmail(me, you,msg.as_string())

server.quit()
```

Comment: What is the full traceback

Comment: SMTPDataError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-16db57abd334> in <module>()
     18 
     19 server.login(me, my_pwd)
---> 20 server.sendmail(me, you,msg.as_string())
     21 server.quit()

/Users/tilin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in sendmail(self, from_addr, to_addrs, msg, mail_options, rcpt_options)
    749         if code != 250:
    750             self.rset()
--> 751             raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
    752         #if we got here then somebody got our mail
    753         return senderrs

Comment: SMTPDataError: (550, '5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender')

Comment: it may be that the mail server does not allow machine based sending.. anti spam..i think the problem is with the mail server persmissions.. maybe contactthem and ask.